# How to track exception of Conga Document generation in Screen flow or LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, conga, conga-composer

If the user has clicked on a link to generate a conga document if the user closed the conga window or if the user got an exception while generating a conga document. How can we handle these scenarios in screen flow or LWC?

Comment: Your will have to check with Conga support.